# Scala: type mismatch with (Any*) => Unit

Tags: scala, variadic-functions

I have an abstract method

```
def updateState: (Any*) => Unit
```

that I am trying to override in a child class in the following way:

```
override def updateState = (sharedOptimizer: Vector[Double],
                            sharedMeanGradient: Vector[Double],
                            sharedHistoricalGradients: Array[Vector[Double]]) => {
    ()
}
```

I do not understand why the compiler returns me this error:

```
Error:(75, 81) type mismatch;
 found   : (Vector[Double], Vector[Double], Array[Vector[Double]]) => Unit
 required: Any* => Unit
```

Isn't the type `Any*` supposed to mean "any number of arguments of any type" ?

Comment: It is supposed to mean that. So, why are you trying to override it by a method that takes exactly three arguments of type `Vector[Double]`, `Vector[Double]` and `Array[Vector[Double]]`? What if I wanted to pass `System.out`, and `"Pizza"` to it? Two is not equal three, and `"Pizza"` is not `Vector[Double]`, so your overriding method cannot cope with `"Pizza"`, thus it cannot cope with `Any*`.

Comment: @andreytyukin Because I want any classes that extends my class to have a method `updateState` but the implementation is totally different depending on the subclass. The parameters might differ too. Maybe there is another, cleaner way of doing it but I don't know..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The type `Any*` is just a normal type, just like `Int` or `List[String]`.
Just as you cannot override a method

```
def foo(x: List[String]): Unit
```

by

```
def foo(x: Int): Unit
```

you can also not override

```
def updateState: (Any*) => Unit
```

by

```
def updateState:
 (Vector[Double], Vector[Double], Array[Vector[Double]]) => Unit
```

because `(Vec[D], Vec[D], Arr[Vec[D]])` is not a supertype of `Any*`, i.e. there are many things that can be passed as `Any*` which are not `(Vec[D], Vec[D], Arr[Vec[D]])`.

If you do not want to hardcode the state type right away, parameterize your class by it:

```
trait Foo[S] {
  def updateState: S => Unit
}
```

or make it into a type member:

```
trait Foo {
  type State
  def updateState: State => Unit
}
```

then you can override it in subclasses:

```
object Bar extends Foo[Int] {
  override def updateState: Int => Unit = 
    x => println("State is now " + x)
}
```

or

```
object Bar extends Foo {
  type State = Int
  override def updateState: Int => Unit = ???
}
```

depending on which option you choose.

Comment: The method with the type member is very elegant, thanks for the solution !

Comment: @ArthurDeschamps It depends more on how the class is used than on the inner structure of the class itself. If you often want to constrain the type `State` from the outside, it's easier to declare it a type parameter. If all other classes usually do not care about what `State` is, it's easier to keep it as type member. Hope that this additional decision criterion is helpful...